# Performance degraded after shrinking

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, shrink, performance-tuning

I was cleaning up database (SQL Server 2012 SE) by deleting old data and truncating some unnecessary tables. After deleting and truncating data performance improved and had 67% free spaces out of 16 GB database. Then run following command to shrink database with 10% free space.

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (databasename, 10);
GO
```

After that database reduced to 7GB but having performance problem, see that attach screenshot. By the way, I also rebuild indexes but no luck. Getting low application performance index (Apdex) alert from New Relic app monitoring tool.

[image]

Look at the DMV query results, at least tweenty queries taking more then 1000ms! I had only 2 queries that exceed 1000ms limit.

[image]

Comment: hey i answered but didn't see you already reindexed.  Can you run the query found here and double check your fragmentation count is low?

Comment: Ali, thanks for the quick response. Max avg_fragmentation_in_percent is 95.74, page_count 94

Comment: Thanks that's for 1 tiny database from what I can tell.  94 page count is really low.  do you only have 1 tiny table in the DB?  If not, you might not have been in the DB or somehow ran it on 1 table.  Let us know. Standing by

Comment: If the scale on the left is cpm, calls per minute, hasn't performance actually increased?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ  it showing extra throughput without any special reason which may indicates I/O bottlenecks, if you notice top of the last section has low application performance index(Apdex) alerts(light red shadows), newrelic is notifying alerts for the low Apdex.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ response time graph also has been added.

Comment: Are you concerned about the database response times or about the newrelic alerts? Do you have any reason to believe that a .1 ms response time change triggers the alerts? You seem to have spikes in your response time chart that don't match up with newrelic alerts too.

Comment: @TomV updated question, see DMV query results

Comment: You say you rebuilt the indexes? How? Did you also update statistis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit:
Will delete this shortly or update based on answer to question. Realized OP mentioned he DID rebuild indexes already.

Shrinking a SQL Server database causes the data to get massively fragmented due to how the algorithm works.  You'll want to usually presize so you don't have to shrink but don't have to worry about growths too much either.  Always easier to grow a live DB with IFI than to shrink and reindex.

Paul Randal has a great post about this in depth [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/).  You will want to reindex and check your fragmentation prior and after using this script ripped off [here](https://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/sql-server-check-index-fragmentation-on-all-indexes-in-a-database/):

```
SELECT dbschemas.[name] as 'Schema', 
dbtables.[name] as 'Table', 
dbindexes.[name] as 'Index',
indexstats.alloc_unit_type_desc,
indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
indexstats.page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
WHERE indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc
```

Comment: So, removing and recreating indexes (with high fragmentation) will help?

Comment: if performance degrades after shrinking, reindexing tables with high fragmentation is a very common solution, unless there are other issues present as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you shrink your database, you are fragmenting the data file.  Any database I have ever managed, always grows.  So lets say I shrink a database file, not something else at the Operating System (OS) uses the disk sectors that were freed up.  Now when the database has to grow, the operating system can't give the database file contiguous disk sectors anymore, so it gives it what it can.

SUMMARY:
Never shrink a database file.  Sure free up space, but don't shrink it.